# PHP Json looping to extract data

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have json variable.

When I do `var_dump` it the result will be like this:

```
array(2) { ["refQualifier"]=> string(1) "S" ["refNumber"]=> int(1) } 
array(2) { ["refQualifier"]=> string(1) "S" ["refNumber"]=> int(2) } 
array(2) { ["refQualifier"]=> string(1) "B" ["refNumber"]=> int(2) }
```

When I do `print_r` it will be like this:

```
Array ( [refQualifier] => S [refNumber] => 1 ) 1
Array ( [refQualifier] => S [refNumber] => 2 ) 1
Array ( [refQualifier] => B [refNumber] => 2 ) 1
```

My question is how to loop it. I need to extract `refNumber` . And I'm using PHP and Laravel.

Comment: what have you managed so far?

Comment: Use `foreach($json as $item){$item['refNumber']}`

Comment: this is my json variable

https://pastebin.com/2XJ0sbsZ

Answer (score 0):

you can directly fetch as array

First json_decode your json data then pass in foreach loop

```
foreach($recommendation->response as $recomend)
  {
     foreach($recomend as $rec)
     {
        foreach($rec->segmentFlightRef as $segment)
        {
            foreach($segment as $userData)
            {
                foreach ($userData as $data)
                {
                    print_r($data->refQualifier);
                }

            }

        }
     }

  }
```

Comment: it gives an error

Illegal string offset 'refQualifier' (View: /var/www/soap/resources/views/amediusmaster.blade.php)

Comment: what issue did u get ? replace $result with your variable

Comment: this is my json variable
https://pastebin.com/U2SDL8yy

this my view blade code 

https://pastebin.com/REP9ZD0N

i want to get ref number

Comment: I have updated the answer. Check weather it helps you

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($json as $item) { 
   echo $item['refNumber'];
}
```

Can also be done using Blade syntax in a view like this:

```
@foreach ($json as $item)

   {{ $item['refNumber'] }}

@endforeach
```

Comment: this is my json variable
https://pastebin.com/U2SDL8yy

this my view blade code 

https://pastebin.com/REP9ZD0N

i want to get ref number

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have associative array like this

```
$data = [
    ['refQualified' => "S", 'refNumber' => 1],
    ['refQualified' => "S", 'refNumber' => 2],
    ['refQualified' => "B", 'refNumber' => 2]
];
```

and to access each `refNumber` in your views can do it like this

```
@foreach($datas as $data)
   {{ $item['refNumber'] }}
@endforeach
```